# Flutter web asset images not displaying when deployed to web server

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have created a `flutter web` project which uses network images and asset images, everything works fine when debugging on my pc but when I deploy it to a web server, the network images work fine but the asset images dont show at all. When I Inspect the page in the web browsers consol, I get the error below:

```
$1 @ window.dart:120
/assets/slack.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()
window.dart:120 Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/slack.png" (503)

$1 @ window.dart:120
/assets/flutterLogo.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()
window.dart:120 Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/flutterLogo.png" (503)

$1 @ window.dart:120
/assets/kross.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()
window.dart:120 Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/kross.jpg" (503)

$1 @ window.dart:120
/assets/codingRocket2.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded
```

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68417207/667586

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add photos to pubspec.yaml file and upload your assets folder to web server. Probably it is about not uploading folder

Comment: worked like a charm. I did not have to add them to `pubspec.yaml` tho.

Comment: @Norbert hey this is not working out for me. I have my assets folder uploaded just fine with all the images declared in pubspec.yaml

Comment: I've added path to every image in pubspec.yaml, but it still isn't working. And what exactly did you mean, when you were saying *upload your assets folder to web server* ?

Comment: @MayurAgarwal when I answered this question Flutter Web is in beta stage so I don't know what happened in stable version.

Comment: Ok, Should I move assets folder under web folder ?

Comment: To clarify, you should add your assets folder into your web folder. Make sure your pubspec.yaml references this web folder.

Answer (score 15):

You should perhaps check if the file is available as part of your deployment. `404` is the usual error code you received for resource not found. `503` is something related to the server availability or server errors. I would do the following.

**Step 1. Check the `build` folder**

Try running the `flutter build web` command in your project and inspect the build folder. 
Assuming a `pubspec.yaml` with following asset configurations.

```yaml
  assets:
    - js/plotly_hookup.js
    - js/plotly-latest.min.js
    - images/
    - screen_shot.png
```

I would expect the following inside my `build\web\assets` folder.

[image: Screen shot of build folder layout]

If this is not working as shown, then its time to inspect the `pubspec.yaml` file and correct the paths.

**Step 2: check your hosted folder**

Ensure the files as shown above are available in your server where this folder is hosted.
Also verify if the server has any configurations to be made specifically for image files or types of images files.

Comment: Hey man, didn't help. I checked all my files are there but the asset images are not showing up.

Comment: @devDeejay Can you check if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62466271/3043944)  helps you. There could be reasons how you access the asset image especially if you host the web app.

Answer (score 8):

Mine was perfectly working with development, when I deploy the build the logos were missing.

I fixed it by using HTML rendering while building the web assets

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html --release
```

Comment: I feel like this answer shouldn't have been here, since it's the complete opposite of the question... but it saved me. Thanks!!!

Comment: IDK how you end up with your thought, op is looking for a solution to the missing assets file in his prod env, and that's the same one I encountered too.. anyway happy to help!

Comment: My apologies! I absolutely read your statement wrong. I misread "development" as deployed. I spent hours looking for a solution, so no doubt my brain wasn't functioning 100%. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

For Flutter Web 3.0:

your pubspec.yaml:

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

test:

```
Image.asset("images/logo.png");
```

deploy:

```
Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png");
```

Worked for me!!!

Comment: I don't get it. Are you rewriting all your asset paths before deploying, then reverting back ? 
Why can the build auto-append the `assets/` prefix to the paths if that's the expected behavior ?

Comment: @TheGioiSo is onto something. I have my images in my pubspec.yaml defined as `- assets/images/` but when I do `flutter build web` I can see they end up placed in `assets/assets/images/`. If after building you go into the build folder and move the image files back down to their intended location at `assets/images/` it works as expected when deployed. This is probably an issue to raise with the team behind the flutter build tools if it hasn't been already.

Comment: this is wired indeed, maybe it's a flutter bug?

Answer (score 6):

Just do this with flutter 2.2.0 then you are all set.

```dart
flutter run -d chrome --web-port=8080  --web-renderer html //port is optional
```

Answer (score 6):

Network Images are Failed to load When Run the Flutter Code on web browser. it’s because of HTML renderer issue.

you can run flutter code using following command or edit android studio settings for run .

flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html

Two possible solution for Image Rendering Issue on Flutter web. Check it here https://youtu.be/U0Ez4CS6frc

Answer (score 2):

In my case there was a STRANGE (as there is no error in desktop or native mobile) error only in mobile browsers, so make sure check your deployed application with a remote debugger on chrome while you are connected to your mobile device.

chrome://inspect/#devices

a currently working solution ...

```
flutter build web --release --web-renderer canvaskit
```

```
Flutter 2.8.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 77d935af4d (7 weeks ago) • 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
Engine • revision 890a5fca2e
Tools • Dart 2.15.1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. first check if the assets folder is in your web folder.
2. while accessing the assets try it writing "assets" two times. for example - "assets/assets/slack.png"

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to the permissions of the images in the asset folder.
Right click on your webpage to `inspect` and click on `Console`

If you have the following message:

```
main.dart.js:7090          GET  
https://mywebsite.com/assets/images/Test/180229115.jpg 403 (Forbidden)
```

You might want to check permissions for your image files with `ls -la` on your server

I had the following:

```
-rwxr----- image1.jpg
-rwxr----- image2.jpg
-rwxr----- etc
```

Then change them to public read with:

```
chmod 644 *`
```

Output:

```
-rw-r--r-- image1.jpg
-rw-r--r-- image2.jpg
-rw-r--r-- etc
```

And reload your index.html, should now work!

Comment: My exact issue, revealed after realizing the asset gives 403, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
  assets:
    - assets/
```

And your folder is like assets/images
then in local run, it will work fine if you open image as /images/image_name.png etc
but when you build for web, it will not include the /images folder
so you have to add it like

```
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images
```

Now it will include the assets/assets/images folder in the web build folder

Edit: Also you'll need to implement a logic to check if its a web then assets location will be assets/assets/images and on ios/android it'll ne assets/images

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue of asset images not showing up when deploying a flutter web project to a web server by following either of the two options:

1. Run with: `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html`
2. Add the following to web/index.html:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
</script>
```

You can try either of the two options and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was I was using `Image.network` instead of `Image.asset` which did not cause an error when running locally as the images were viewed fine locally and only caused the images to not be viewed in deployment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was also accessing the assets/assets folder. I have moved one level back, copying assets/assets/img -> assets/img and it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't realise the cAsE of the filenames on some of my images didn't match what I had in my code, so for example I had an image named `assets/images/myimage.png`, but I was referencing it as `Image.asset('assets/images/MyImage.png')`. This worked fine in development (I guess because the dev web server is NOT CASE SENSITIVE when serving files) but broke when I uploaded to my web server (Digital Ocean app platform - which I'm guessing IS case sensitive).