# Firebase, Flutter Web App Works locally, but when deployed images are not shown

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I have a flutter web app which works well locally but after deploying it using

```
firebase deploy
```

the images are not shown in the website, I have checked if the assets have been uploaded by tracing, e.g. my_app.firebaseapp.com/assets/assets/card.jpg. (And the image is there, so it has uploaded properly but for some reason its not being displayed on the homepage itself).

Url: https://websitehostingtry.web.app/#/

https://websitehostingtry.web.app/assets/images/card.jpg

when running the same locally:

```
flutter run -d chrome --release
```

My Pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: website_try
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - images/
```

In my dart code I just changed the default code to add Image after counter...

```
Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Image.network('assets/images/card.jpg'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tested viewing the website on a different browser? I have a portfolio website that looks normal on Chrome but on Safari, images are not visible sometimes. Try on different browsers and maybe we can understand the problem better.

Comment: Yes I have tested it on safari and chrome, no results. I have also tried creating a new flutter web app, a simple one which displays only one image, doesn't work.

Comment: In my case, I didn't mentioned assets/ for the Image file in Image.Asset.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I checked the page you shared, this is one of the typical issues when you deploy to any hosting service. Its usually caused by the way you access the image.

One of your network request URL looks like this in the live page. You can check this in the developer tools of chrome.

https://websitehostingtry.web.app/assets/card.jpg

when I checked the `flutter_service_worker.js` it shows the following listing where the assets are.

```js
'use strict';
const CACHE_NAME = 'flutter-app-cache';
const RESOURCES = {
  "index.html": "7136835e515d34b7b84f2ae95aff570f",
"/": "7136835e515d34b7b84f2ae95aff570f",
"main.dart.js": "2368f8417bf6d56998d2eb9d8db6dc09",
"favicon.png": "5dcef449791fa27946b3d35ad8803796",
"icons/Icon-192.png": "ac9a721a12bbc803b44f645561ecb1e1",
"icons/Icon-512.png": "96e752610906ba2a93c65f8abe1645f1",
"manifest.json": "6c43261a82a59e92d3d5d2b6824ddd9a",
"assets/LICENSE": "34da31f697be5f2fcfacf877df9adb0a",
"assets/AssetManifest.json": "7701bf8932c1b66ef282029ec69bb8ee",
"assets/FontManifest.json": "01700ba55b08a6141f33e168c4a6c22f",
"assets/packages/cupertino_icons/assets/CupertinoIcons.ttf": "115e937bb829a890521f72d2e664b632",
"assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf": "56d3ffdef7a25659eab6a68a3fbfaf16",
"assets/assets/card.jpg": "6cbe9266e9c097ee95ab2e2c36048ee8"
};
```

Based on my analysis I am guessing in your code you are probably referring to the image as follows.

```dart
Image.asset('/assets/card.jpg');
```

**or**

```dart
Image.network('/assets/card.jpg');
```

This will map from the root domain and hence its looking up for https://websitehostingtry.web.app/assets/card.jpg.

So one approach would be to remove the additional forward slash before `assets` in the path. for e.g.

```dart
Image.asset('assets/card.jpg');
```

Or if you prefer `Image.network` then following would work.

```dart
Image.network('assets/assets/card.jpg');
```

Another approach and clearer one would be to create a new directory images and place the card.jpg in side that so that its clear whats inside.

> Rationale is to name your folder by content type for clarity.

Change `pubspec.yaml` to

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - images/
```

Then change your code to following.

```dart
Image.asset('images/card.jpg');
```

or

```dart
Image.network('assets/images/card.jpg');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If this didn't help please share your `pubspec.yaml` and your folder structure along the with the code where you access the `Image`.

Comment: glad it helped you. :)

Comment: My pubspec assets are like this -   assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/bg1.jpg
    - assets/mayur2.jpg       And I am accessing the third image like , *Image.asset('assets/mayur2.jpg')*        But still, nothing is happening.

Comment: I don't understand why `assets/image.jpg` turns into `assets/assets/image.jpg` in the first place!? Very counterintuitive...

Answer (score 5):

**pubspec.yaml**

```
assets:
- assets/images/
```

Remember when you are in **debug mode**, you will have to do this

```
Image.network('assets/images/pic.jpeg')
```

but when the web app is **deployed**, it should be written like this:

```
Image.network('assets/assets/images/pic.jpeg')
```

you have to prepend an extra *assets/* to the asset path so that it could work when deployed

So use this approach:

- import this file

  `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';`
- define a string that will take values depending on the DevelopmentMode

  `String releasePath = kDebugMode ? '' : 'assets/';`
- use this string everywhere in your project like this

  `Image.network('${releasePath}assets/images/pic.jpeg')`

you are all good to go.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

**The problem:**

pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - images/
```

Initially, I was loading an image in flutter app as

```
Image.asset("images/banner.png")
```

The web app loads the image perfectly on localhost. But, as I deploy the web app on Firebase hosting, everything works fine, except that the image doesn't load!

**The solution:**

I inspected the Firebase hosting deployment as

```
firebase deploy --debug
```

In the terminal, I searched for `banner.png` to find that the image is uploaded, but is being accessed by a different path!

```
"/assets/assets/images/banner.png"
```

So, I changed the access path while loading the image by prepending `assets/`, as

```
Image.asset("assets/images/banner.png")
```

Now, it loads the image on localhost and from Firebase hosting, alike!

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem and I think your solution would help me. But I dont't understand where exactly you changed the access path while loading the image by prepending assets/ .... can you help me out here ?