# Flutter web: Some png assets not loaded (404) status

Tags: docker, flutter, nginx, flutter-web

I added web support to my flutter mobile project. project built good and in build time there are no error or a problem.

After build project, **web folder** created inside **build folder**.Inside web folder i have these files and folders:

```
$ ls
assets  favicon.png  flutter_service_worker.js  icons  index.html  main.dart.js  manifest.json  version.json
```

Inside assets folder,there is assets folder again :

```
/build/web/assets
$ ls
AssetManifest.json  assets  FontManifest.json  fonts  NOTICES  packages
```

Inside this assets, there are assets of project:

```
/build/web/assets/assets
$ ls
fonts  images  male.svg  svgs  webfonts
```

I copy images and svgs folders into last path `/build/web/assets`.Then I added web folder into `/usr/share/nginx/html` path of nginx container by running this:

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8081:80 --name web -v /mnt/Project/Flutter/Projects/app_web/build/web:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

And then in chrome it this url `http://localhost:8081/` i see my page.

Problem:

Some png status files have **404** in **DevTools** of chrome. I see this url `http://localhost:8081/assets/assets/images/CardMask.png`

[image]

`CardMask.png` also exist at this location:

```
/build/web/assets/assets/images
$ ls -la
total 569
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   4096 Nov  3 14:13 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   4096 Nov  3 14:13 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   4319 Nov  3 14:13 CardMask.png
```

and in container:

```
root@442f35f12938:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls
assets       flutter_service_worker.js  index.html    manifest.json
favicon.png  icons          main.dart.js  version.json
root@442f35f12938:/usr/share/nginx/html# cd assets/
root@442f35f12938:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets# ls
AssetManifest.json  FontManifest.json  NOTICES  assets  fonts  images  packages  svgs
root@442f35f12938:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets# cd assets/
root@442f35f12938:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/assets# ls
fonts  images  male.svg  svgs  webfonts
root@442f35f12938:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/assets# cd images/
root@442f35f12938:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/assets/images# ls
3DBoxes.png   Intersection.svg        bime.png     recieptPage.svg  tick.png
At3.svg       OperationMaskGroup.png  mahak.png    theme.jpg
CardMask.png  RightArcMask.png        receipt.png  theme1.png
root@442f35f12938:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/assets/images#
```

I added assets folder in `pubspec.yaml` like this:

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/svgs/
    - assets/svgs/regular/
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/webfonts/
```

What is a problem ?

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.23.0-18.1.pre, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

How can i remove **second assets** in this link : `http://localhost:8081/assets/assets/images/CardMask.png`

If the path be `http://localhost:8081/assets/images/CardMask.png`, i can see my **png** but in `http://localhost:8081/assets/assets/images/CardMask.png` i got **404**

I am using this code to show png :

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  child: ColorFiltered(
    colorFilter:
        ColorFilter.mode(widget.themeColor, BlendMode.srcATop),
    child: kIsWeb
        ? Image.network('assets/images/CardMask.png')
        : Image.asset('assets/images/CardMask.png'),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Could you verify the solutions suggested in these two posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878346/flutter-web-asset-images-not-displaying-when-deployed-to-web-server/58880217#58880217) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292512/firebase-flutter-web-app-works-locally-but-when-deployed-images-are-not-shown/62466271#62466271)

Comment: I checked those links and i can't find problem in my structure. The problem is here : If the link be `http://localhost:8081/assets/images/CardMask.png` everything is good but i don't know why link is `http://localhost:8081/assets/assets/images/CardMask.png` ? Second asset is a problem @AbhilashChandran

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when I uploaded to the server running apache/nginx. I have to move all files and folders in assets/assets to assets manually. I don't know how it runs in my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Base href in index.html file

`<base href="/">`

change / to your path/hosting/domain